# Can we write an indicator function as an integral?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a function from some set $A$ into $\mathbb{R}$, and consider the indicator function $\large\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(-\infty, x]}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Intuitively I feel I can write
$$
\large\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(-\infty, x]}=\int_{-\infty}^x \large\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}\{z\}} \text{dz}
$$
but I have absolutely no idea how this could be proved, given $f$ is arbitrary. Is it even correct? I wish I had more to say about this but it is quite confusing to me. Perhaps this would be proved via some probability/measure-theory argument? Any thoughts on this would be great!

[This is not a homework question, I am just very curious.]

Comment: You are taking an integral of a function from real numbers to real valued functions. Are you meaning to define the function pointwise?

Comment: Like $\large\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(-\infty, x]}(w)=\int_{-\infty}^x \large\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}\{z\}}(w) \text{dz}$ ?

Comment: In full $\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(B)}:A\to \{0,1\}$ for $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I'm not sure on the exact interpretation to make progress, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: I don't know if what you wrote is correct, but considering [these integral reprsentations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=heavisidetheta%28x%29+integral+representation) of a special indicator function, I think it can be done.